# os.rename does not raise FileExistsError when file exists

Tags: python, wsl-2

I have a `file_rename` mechanism which I want to improve with a simple `try/except` block that will check if the renamed file does already exists in the directory.

I prepared in my directory 2 files: `data.txt` and `old_data.txt`. Function should throw an exception, as `old_data.txt` already exists, which implies that data was processed in the past.

However, the below code is not working, as it is still renaming the `data.txt` file. I'd appreciate any assistance and guidance on this.

```
@staticmethod
def file_rename(file, dir):
    source_file_new_name = "old_" + file
    try:
        os.path.isfile(dir + source_file_new_name)
        os.rename(os.path.join(dir, file), os.path.join(dir, source_file_new_name))
    except FileExistsError:
        raise FileExistsError("this file was already processed")
```

With Rafał's and BrokenBenchmark hint I came up with below version but not sure if its enough pythonic ;)

```
class FileExistsError(Exception):
    pass

@staticmethod
def file_rename(file, dir):
    source_file_new_name = "old_" + file

    if os.path.isfile(dir + source_file_new_name):
        raise FileExistsError("this file was already processed!")
    else:
        os.rename(os.path.join(dir, file), os.path.join(dir, source_file_new_name))
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu on WSL2/Windows 10

Comment: Excellent; edit that into your post. It's important, writing answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

os.path.isfile method just returns True (if a file exists) or False (if it doesn't). Use an if statement to check its result before calling os.rename.

Comment: Not sure how pythonic this would be but `raise` can be used within `if` block too: `if os.path.isfile(dir + source_file_new_name):
            os.rename(os.path.join(dir, file), os.path.join(dir, source_file_new_name))
            raise FileExistsError("this file was already processed")`

Comment: You can but should you? Honestly, that mostly depends on your personal preference on how to handle logic errors. E.g. lookup [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-EAFP) (Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission) as a common Python coding style.

Answer (score 4):

Your code assumes that `os.rename` will raise a `FileExistsError`. **That assumption can only be made if the code is being run on Windows.** [The Python docs for `os.rename()` state](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename):

> `os.rename(src, dst, *, src_dir_fd=None, dst_dir_fd=None)`
>
> Rename the file or directory *src* to *dst*. If *dst* exists, the operation will fail with an `OSError` subclass in a number of cases:
>
> On Windows, if *dst* exists a `FileExistsError` is always raised.
>
> On Unix, ... **[i]f both [*src* and *dst*] are files, *dst* it [sic] will be replaced silently if the user has permission.**

To resolve this issue, use an `if` statement with `.isfile()` instead, rather than relying on a `try/except` that hinges on behavior that isn't portable in order to work:

```py
def file_rename(file, dir):
    source_file_new_name = "old_" + file
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.isfile(dir + source_file_new_name)):
        os.rename(os.path.join(dir, file), os.path.join(dir, source_file_new_name))
```

Comment: Not sure how pythonic this would be but raise can be used within if block too: if os.path.isfile(dir + source_file_new_name):             os.rename(os.path.join(dir, file), os.path.join(dir, source_file_new_name))             raise FileExistsError("this file was already processed")

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't raise an error just to immediately catch it; it adds unnecessary complexity to your code, since an `if/else` would be simpler. But this is more subjective than the original issue at hand.

Comment: In my case I will stick to it as I need to break code execution in order to not load data into database. That single chunk I posted is part of ELT script.