# Deleting certain part of file names

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I have a set of file names I am looping over to delete one aspect at the end of all file names. Currently I have some code that will search for a string in the filename and delete it. However the part of the file I want to get rid of changes a little. I was looking to use some characters one would use for glob.glob(file) but Im sure you can't do that. Is there a way to do this? Maybe split() and rewrite the name?

Here are a couple files. I want to get rid of the (Ni??Nj??)

```
a-optimized.new.10_10_50-775-11_11_60.Ni01Nj10.txt
a-optimized.new.10_10_60-755-11_11_60.Ni00Nj01.txt
a-optimized.new.10_10_40-715-11_11_60.Ni00Nj10.txt
```

here is the code I am working with

```
import os
rootdir = r"C:\Py Practice\Sorted File Groups\nmdAnmd"
str = ".Ni*Nj*"
for filename in os.listdir(rootdir):
    if str in filename:    
        filepath = os.path.join(rootdir, filename)
        newfilepath = os.path.join(rootdir, filename.replace(str, ""))
        os.rename(filepath, newfilepath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a matching pattern instead and replace with an empty string.

```
\.Ni\d*Nj\d*
```

The pattern matches:

- `\.Ni` Match `.Ni`
- `\d*` Match optional digits
- `Nj` Match `Nj`
- `\d*` Match optional digits

Example

```
import os
import re

rootdir = r"C:\Py Practice\Sorted File Groups\nmdAnmd"
pattern = r"\.Ni\d*Nj\d*"

for filename in os.listdir(rootdir):
    filepath = os.path.join(rootdir, filename)
    newfilepath = os.path.join(rootdir, re.sub(pattern, "", filename))
    os.rename(filepath, newfilepath)
```

Output

```
a-optimized.new.10_10_50-775-11_11_60.txt
a-optimized.new.10_10_60-755-11_11_60.txt
a-optimized.new.10_10_40-715-11_11_60.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try. Would it be possible to get rid of it all together? The NiNj also? If not the first way works fine.

Comment: @LandonGaber I have added an example how to remove the whole match.

Comment: This is givin me an error

Comment: File "c:\Py Practice\cutNiJi.py", line 12, in <module>
    os.rename(filepath, newfilepath)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:

Comment: It is working for the first file, but then it stops and then trips that error

Comment: @LandonGaber You are renaming files, which can cause renaming it to an already existing file so you would have to account for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990725/error-183-when-using-python-os-rename and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107352/force-overwrite-in-os-rename and for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71542569/os-rename-does-not-raise-fileexistserror-when-file-exists